# C++ map::find() in stl

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, find

```
map <int, map<int, string>> DP;
if( DP.find( ? ) != DP.end() )
{
    // have found
}
```

How to fill in (). It seem like two dimension. I know how to deal with one dimension, for example:

```
map<int, string> DP;
if( DP.find(1) != DP.end() )
{
    // have found
}
```

But I don't know how to deal with two dimension.

Comment: You may also consider directly using `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string>`

Answer (score 1):

One dimension at a time:

```
auto it1 = DP.find(1);
if (it1 != DP.end()) {
  auto it2 = it1->find(2);
  if (it2 != it1->end()) {
    // found: it2->second
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **Kerrek SB**`s codes exists a little problem. The way of visiting second(inner) dimension should be like this:

```
auto OuterIter = DP.find(1);
if (OuterIter != DP.end())
{
    auto InnerMap  = OuterIter->second;
    auto InnerIter = InnerMap.find(0);
    if (InnerIter != InnerMap.end())
    {
        // found the second(inner) dimension element
    }
}
```

And you can think about **chtz**`s advise: *You may also consider directly using std::map, std::string>*